# How to detect if pager is active on page?

Tags: 7, paging

Is it possible to detect programatically, if page on current URL contains some pager?

I have views with pager on my website. I can see "page" GET argument in URL, but not in first page. So I cannot detect pager by check:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['page']))
?>
```

Because first page (page=0) has no GET argument

I tried to use function theme_pager, I registered overriding function to theme_pager in my hook_theme_registry_alter:

```
<?php
$theme_registry['pager']['function'] = 'mymodule_theme_pager';
?>
```

But then I need to override whole function theme_pager in my custom module. I think there can be some simplier solution.
Maybe there exists some method like is_pager() or something similar?

thanks for help

//EDIT: I need to achieve, that metatags rel="prev" and rel="next" will be generated, when pager is active

//EDIT2: I found solution for pagers from views: I can get information about pager in hook_views_post_execute. It is sufficient for may case (I have only pagers from view) although it would be good to know, if there is some general solution for all pagers on website.

Comment: Mind if I ask what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Relevant thread here:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1567684
With related module here:
https://github.com/nlisgo/nextprev_links